# Error Build Module DbKey Angular

Tags: angular, npm, build

Boa Tarde.

Estou tentando buildar o meu projeto Angular, porém, o mesmo apresenta a falta de um modulo chamado DbKeys, tentei reinstalar o pacote node_modules usando o comando `npm install`, tentei limpar o cache, tentei baixar o modulo individualmente, porém, todas as medidas adotadas anteriormente sem sucesso.

**Segue o erro que recebo ao buildar meu projeto Angular:**

```
root@instance-4 /v/l/j/w/B/g/G/G/ClientApp# ng b

Date: 2019-02-24T20:28:45.329Z
Hash: 198ac103d49163456ee1
Time: 18622ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 696 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 92.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 311 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.css, styles.css.map (styles) 272 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/app/services/auth.service.ts(14,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './db-Keys'.
src/app/services/configuration.service.ts(10,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './db-Keys'.
```

**Segue as configurações do meu projeto:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.15.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.1
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.1
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.29.0
```

**Log de debug do npm:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--prod' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle quickapp@2.6.1~prebuild: quickapp@2.6.1
6 info lifecycle quickapp@2.6.1~build: quickapp@2.6.1
7 verbose lifecycle quickapp@2.6.1~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle quickapp@2.6.1~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace
/BuildDemo/gerenciador-projetos/GerenciadorProjeto/GerenciadorProjeto/ClientApp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/u
sr/games:/snap/bin:/var/lib/jenkins/.dotnet/tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/
bin
9 verbose lifecycle quickapp@2.6.1~build: CWD: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BuildDemo/gerenciador-projetos/GerenciadorProjeto/GerenciadorProjeto/Cli
entApp
10 silly lifecycle quickapp@2.6.1~build: Args: [ '-c', 'ng build --extract-css "--prod"' ]
11 silly lifecycle quickapp@2.6.1~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle quickapp@2.6.1~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: quickapp@2.6.1 build: `ng build --extract-css "--prod"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid quickapp@2.6.1
15 verbose cwd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BuildDemo/gerenciador-projetos/GerenciadorProjeto/GerenciadorProjeto/ClientApp
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-1027-gcp
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build" "--" "--prod"
18 verbose node v10.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error quickapp@2.6.1 build: `ng build --extract-css "--prod"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the quickapp@2.6.1 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

### #

**src/app/services/auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from "@angular/route";
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { LocalStoreManager } from './local-store-manager.service';
import { EndpointFactory } from './endpoint-factory.service';
import { ConfigurationService } from './configuration.service';
import { DBkeys } from './db-Keys';
import { JwtHelper } from './jwt-helper';
import { Utilities } from './utilities';
import { LoginResponse, IdToken } from '../models/login-response.model';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { Permission, PermissionNames, PermissionValues } from '../models/permission.model';
import { ProjectManager } from '../models/projectManager.model';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public get loginUrl() { return this.configurations.loginUrl; }
  public get homeUrl() { return this.configurations.homeUrl; }

  public loginRedirectUrl: string;
  public logoutRedirectUrl: string;

  public reLoginDelegate: () => void;

  private previousIsLoggedInCheck = false;
  private _loginStatus = new Subject<boolean>();


  constructor(private router: Router, private configurations: ConfigurationService, private endpointFactory: EndpointFactory, private localStorage: LocalStoreManager) {
    this.initializeLoginStatus();
  }


  private initializeLoginStatus() {
    this.localStorage.getInitEvent().subscribe(() => {
      this.reevaluateLoginStatus();
    });
  }


  gotoPage(page: string, preserveParams = true) {

    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParamsHandling: preserveParams ? "merge" : "", preserveFragment: preserveParams
    };


    this.router.navigate([page], navigationExtras);
  }


  redirectLoginUser() {
    let redirect = this.loginRedirectUrl && this.loginRedirectUrl != '/' && this.loginRedirectUrl != ConfigurationService.defaultHomeUrl ? this.loginRedirectUrl : this.homeUrl;
    this.loginRedirectUrl = null;


    let urlParamsAndFragment = Utilities.splitInTwo(redirect, '#');
    let urlAndParams = Utilities.splitInTwo(urlParamsAndFragment.firstPart, '?');

    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      fragment: urlParamsAndFragment.secondPart,
      queryParams: Utilities.getQueryParamsFromString(urlAndParams.secondPart),
      queryParamsHandling: "merge"
    };

    this.router.navigate([urlAndParams.firstPart], navigationExtras);
  }


  redirectLogoutUser() {
    let redirect = this.logoutRedirectUrl ? this.logoutRedirectUrl : this.loginUrl;
    this.logoutRedirectUrl = null;

    this.router.navigate([redirect]);
  }


  redirectForLogin() {
    this.loginRedirectUrl = this.router.url;
    this.router.navigate([this.loginUrl]);
  }


  reLogin() {

    this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN);

    if (this.reLoginDelegate) {
      this.reLoginDelegate();
    }
    else {
      this.redirectForLogin();
    }
  }


  refreshLogin() {
    return this.endpointFactory.getRefreshLoginEndpoint<LoginResponse>().pipe(
      map(response => this.processLoginResponse(response, this.rememberMe)));
  }


  login(userName: string, password: string, rememberMe?: boolean) {

    if (this.isLoggedIn)
      this.logout();

    return this.endpointFactory.getLoginEndpoint<LoginResponse>(userName, password).pipe(
      map(response => this.processLoginResponse(response, rememberMe)));
  }


  private processLoginResponse(response: LoginResponse, rememberMe: boolean) {

    let accessToken = response.access_token;

    if (accessToken == null)
      throw new Error("Received accessToken was empty");

    let idToken = response.id_token;
    let refreshToken = response.refresh_token || this.refreshToken;
    let expiresIn = response.expires_in;

    let tokenExpiryDate = new Date();
    tokenExpiryDate.setSeconds(tokenExpiryDate.getSeconds() + expiresIn);

    let accessTokenExpiry = tokenExpiryDate;

    let jwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
    let decodedIdToken = <IdToken>jwtHelper.decodeToken(response.id_token);

    let permissions: PermissionValues[] = Array.isArray(decodedIdToken.permission) ? decodedIdToken.permission : [decodedIdToken.permission];

    if (!this.isLoggedIn)
      this.configurations.import(decodedIdToken.configuration);

    let user = new User(
      decodedIdToken.sub,
      decodedIdToken.name,
      decodedIdToken.fullname,
      decodedIdToken.email,
      decodedIdToken.jobtitle,
      decodedIdToken.phone,
      Array.isArray(decodedIdToken.role) ? decodedIdToken.role : [decodedIdToken.role]);
    user.isEnabled = true;

    this.saveUserDetails(user, permissions, accessToken, idToken, refreshToken, accessTokenExpiry, rememberMe);

    this.reevaluateLoginStatus(user);

    return user;
  }


  private saveUserDetails(user: User, permissions: PermissionValues[], accessToken: string, idToken: string, refreshToken: string, expiresIn: Date, rememberMe: boolean) {

    if (rememberMe) {
      this.localStorage.savePermanentData(accessToken, DBkeys.ACCESS_TOKEN);
      this.localStorage.savePermanentData(idToken, DBkeys.ID_TOKEN);
      this.localStorage.savePermanentData(refreshToken, DBkeys.REFRESH_TOKEN);
      this.localStorage.savePermanentData(expiresIn, DBkeys.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN);
      this.localStorage.savePermanentData(permissions, DBkeys.USER_PERMISSIONS);
      this.localStorage.savePermanentData(user, DBkeys.CURRENT_USER);
    }
    else {
      this.localStorage.saveSyncedSessionData(accessToken, DBkeys.ACCESS_TOKEN);
      this.localStorage.saveSyncedSessionData(idToken, DBkeys.ID_TOKEN);
      this.localStorage.saveSyncedSessionData(refreshToken, DBkeys.REFRESH_TOKEN);
      this.localStorage.saveSyncedSessionData(expiresIn, DBkeys.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN);
      this.localStorage.saveSyncedSessionData(permissions, DBkeys.USER_PERMISSIONS);
      this.localStorage.saveSyncedSessionData(user, DBkeys.CURRENT_USER);
    }

    this.localStorage.savePermanentData(rememberMe, DBkeys.REMEMBER_ME);
  }



  logout(): void {
    this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.ID_TOKEN);
    this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.REFRESH_TOKEN);
    this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN);
    this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.USER_PERMISSIONS);
    this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.CURRENT_USER);

    this.configurations.clearLocalChanges();

    this.reevaluateLoginStatus();
  }


  private reevaluateLoginStatus(currentUser?: User) {

    let user = currentUser || this.localStorage.getDataObject<User>(DBkeys.CURRENT_USER);
    let isLoggedIn = user != null;

    if (this.previousIsLoggedInCheck != isLoggedIn) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this._loginStatus.next(isLoggedIn);
      });
    }

    this.previousIsLoggedInCheck = isLoggedIn;
  }


  getLoginStatusEvent(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._loginStatus.asObservable();
  }


  get currentUser(): User {

    let user = this.localStorage.getDataObject<User>(DBkeys.CURRENT_USER);
    this.reevaluateLoginStatus(user);

    return user;
  }


  get userPermissions(): PermissionValues[] {
    return this.localStorage.getDataObject<PermissionValues[]>(DBkeys.USER_PERMISSIONS) || [];
  }

  get accessToken(): string {

    this.reevaluateLoginStatus();
    return this.localStorage.getData(DBkeys.ACCESS_TOKEN);
  }

  get accessTokenExpiryDate(): Date {

    this.reevaluateLoginStatus();
    return this.localStorage.getDataObject<Date>(DBkeys.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN, true);
  }

  get isSessionExpired(): boolean {

    if (this.accessTokenExpiryDate == null) {
      return true;
    }

    return !(this.accessTokenExpiryDate.valueOf() > new Date().valueOf());
  }


  get idToken(): string {

    this.reevaluateLoginStatus();
    return this.localStorage.getData(DBkeys.ID_TOKEN);
  }

  get refreshToken(): string {

    this.reevaluateLoginStatus();
    return this.localStorage.getData(DBkeys.REFRESH_TOKEN);
  }

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.currentUser != null;
  }

  get rememberMe(): boolean {
    return this.localStorage.getDataObject<boolean>(DBkeys.REMEMBER_ME) == true;
  }
}
```

### #

**src/app/services/configuration.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppTranslationService } from './app-translation.service';
import { LocalStoreManager } from './local-store-manager.service';
import { DBkeys } from './db-Keys';
import { Utilities } from './utilities';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';



type UserConfiguration = {
    language: string,
    homeUrl: string,
    theme: string,
    showDashboardStatistics: boolean,
    showDashboardNotifications: boolean,
    showDashboardTodo: boolean,
    showDashboardBanner: boolean
};

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

    public static readonly appVersion: string = "2.6.1";

    public baseUrl = environment.baseUrl || Utilities.baseUrl();
    public loginUrl = environment.loginUrl;
    public fallbackBaseUrl = "http://quickapp.ebenmonney.com";

    //***Specify default configurations here***
    public static readonly defaultLanguage: string = "pt";
    public static readonly defaultHomeUrl: string = "/";
    public static readonly defaultTheme: string = "Default";
    public static readonly defaultShowDashboardStatistics: boolean = true;
    public static readonly defaultShowDashboardNotifications: boolean = true;
    public static readonly defaultShowDashboardTodo: boolean = false;
    public static readonly defaultShowDashboardBanner: boolean = true;
    //***End of defaults***  

    private _language: string = null;
    private _homeUrl: string = null;
    private _theme: string = null;
    private _showDashboardStatistics: boolean = null;
    private _showDashboardNotifications: boolean = null;
    private _showDashboardTodo: boolean = null;
    private _showDashboardBanner: boolean = null;


    constructor(private localStorage: LocalStoreManager, private translationService: AppTranslationService) {
        this.loadLocalChanges();
    }



    private loadLocalChanges() {

        if (this.localStorage.exists(DBkeys.LANGUAGE)) {
            this._language = this.localStorage.getDataObject<string>(DBkeys.LANGUAGE);
            this.translationService.changeLanguage(this._language);
        }
        else {
            this.resetLanguage();
        }

        if (this.localStorage.exists(DBkeys.HOME_URL))
            this._homeUrl = this.localStorage.getDataObject<string>(DBkeys.HOME_URL);

        if (this.localStorage.exists(DBkeys.THEME))
            this._theme = this.localStorage.getDataObject<string>(DBkeys.THEME);

        if (this.localStorage.exists(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_STATISTICS))
            this._showDashboardStatistics = this.localStorage.getDataObject<boolean>(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_STATISTICS);

        if (this.localStorage.exists(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_NOTIFICATIONS))
            this._showDashboardNotifications = this.localStorage.getDataObject<boolean>(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_NOTIFICATIONS);

        if (this.localStorage.exists(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_TODO))
            this._showDashboardTodo = this.localStorage.getDataObject<boolean>(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_TODO);

        if (this.localStorage.exists(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_BANNER))
            this._showDashboardBanner = this.localStorage.getDataObject<boolean>(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_BANNER);
    }


    private saveToLocalStore(data: any, key: string) {
        setTimeout(() => this.localStorage.savePermanentData(data, key));
    }


    public import(jsonValue: string) {

        this.clearLocalChanges();

        if (!jsonValue)
            return;

        let importValue: UserConfiguration = Utilities.JSonTryParse(jsonValue);

        if (importValue.language != null)
            this.language = importValue.language;

        if (importValue.homeUrl != null)
            this.homeUrl = importValue.homeUrl;

        if (importValue.theme != null)
            this.theme = importValue.theme;

        if (importValue.showDashboardStatistics != null)
            this.showDashboardStatistics = importValue.showDashboardStatistics;

        if (importValue.showDashboardNotifications != null)
            this.showDashboardNotifications = importValue.showDashboardNotifications;

        if (importValue.showDashboardTodo != null)
            this.showDashboardTodo = importValue.showDashboardTodo;

        if (importValue.showDashboardBanner != null)
            this.showDashboardBanner = importValue.showDashboardBanner;
    }


    public export(changesOnly = true): string {

        let exportValue: UserConfiguration =
            {
                language: changesOnly ? this._language : this.language,
                homeUrl: changesOnly ? this._homeUrl : this.homeUrl,
                theme: changesOnly ? this._theme : this.theme,
                showDashboardStatistics: changesOnly ? this._showDashboardStatistics : this.showDashboardStatistics,
                showDashboardNotifications: changesOnly ? this._showDashboardNotifications : this.showDashboardNotifications,
                showDashboardTodo: changesOnly ? this._showDashboardTodo : this.showDashboardTodo,
                showDashboardBanner: changesOnly ? this._showDashboardBanner : this.showDashboardBanner
            };

        return JSON.stringify(exportValue);
    }


    public clearLocalChanges() {
        this._language = null;
        this._homeUrl = null;
        this._theme = null;
        this._showDashboardStatistics = null;
        this._showDashboardNotifications = null;
        this._showDashboardTodo = null;
        this._showDashboardBanner = null;

        this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.LANGUAGE);
        this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.HOME_URL);
        this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.THEME);
        this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_STATISTICS);
        this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_NOTIFICATIONS);
        this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_TODO);
        this.localStorage.deleteData(DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_BANNER);

        this.resetLanguage();
    }


    private resetLanguage() {
        let language = this.translationService.useBrowserLanguage();

        if (language) {
            this._language = language;
        }
        else {
            this._language = this.translationService.changeLanguage()
        }
    }




    set language(value: string) {
        this._language = value;
        this.saveToLocalStore(value, DBkeys.LANGUAGE);
        this.translationService.changeLanguage(value);
    }
    get language() {
        if (this._language != null)
            return this._language;

        return ConfigurationService.defaultLanguage;
    }


    set homeUrl(value: string) {
        this._homeUrl = value;
        this.saveToLocalStore(value, DBkeys.HOME_URL);
    }
    get homeUrl() {
        if (this._homeUrl != null)
            return this._homeUrl;

        return ConfigurationService.defaultHomeUrl;
    }


    set theme(value: string) {
        this._theme = value;
        this.saveToLocalStore(value, DBkeys.THEME);
    }
    get theme() {
        if (this._theme != null)
            return this._theme;

        return ConfigurationService.defaultTheme;
    }


    set showDashboardStatistics(value: boolean) {
        this._showDashboardStatistics = value;
        this.saveToLocalStore(value, DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_STATISTICS);
    }
    get showDashboardStatistics() {
        if (this._showDashboardStatistics != null)
            return this._showDashboardStatistics;

        return ConfigurationService.defaultShowDashboardStatistics;
    }


    set showDashboardNotifications(value: boolean) {
        this._showDashboardNotifications = value;
        this.saveToLocalStore(value, DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_NOTIFICATIONS);
    }
    get showDashboardNotifications() {
        if (this._showDashboardNotifications != null)
            return this._showDashboardNotifications;

        return ConfigurationService.defaultShowDashboardNotifications;
    }


    set showDashboardTodo(value: boolean) {
        this._showDashboardTodo = value;
        this.saveToLocalStore(value, DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_TODO);
    }
    get showDashboardTodo() {
        if (this._showDashboardTodo != null)
            return this._showDashboardTodo;

        return ConfigurationService.defaultShowDashboardTodo;
    }


    set showDashboardBanner(value: boolean) {
        this._showDashboardBanner = value;
        this.saveToLocalStore(value, DBkeys.SHOW_DASHBOARD_BANNER);
    }
    get showDashboardBanner() {
        if (this._showDashboardBanner != null)
            return this._showDashboardBanner;

        return ConfigurationService.defaultShowDashboardBanner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adicione os arquivos `src/app/services/auth.service.ts` e `src/app/services/configuration.service.ts`

Comment: Adicionado alterações

Comment: O Angular não está encontrando o arquivo `db-Keys`, verifique o caminho e tente setar uma extensão para ele, provavelmente `.ts`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o db-Keys é um .ts e não um modulo,estava sendo referenciado no import com letra maiúscula, sendo que o correto seria com letra minuscula db-keys, no windows o compilador "ng b" não encontrou esta inconsistência, mas ao buildar no linux ele reclamou.